# How to apply opacity at column right every time the selection changes

Tags: jquery, select, prestashop

I have a problem with the selection and change of opacity to the column where the select is present. In practice I would like that every time the choice is changed, the column changes opacity until the function is loaded. Now I have the following code that works, after making the first choice, if I go again to choose the option of the select does not apply the opacity. Can you tell me where I'm wrong? Thank you so much

```
$('.form-control-select').change(function() {
    $('.product_middle_column').css('opacity','.4');
});
prestashop.on("updatedProduct", function (){
    $('.product_middle_column').css('opacity','');
});


<select class="form-control form-control-select " id="group_6" data-product-attribute="6" name="group[6]">
    <option class="sangue" value="66" title="46">46</option>
    <option class="sangue" value="67" title="45">45</option>
    <option class="sangue" value="68" title="42" selected="selected">42</option>
    <option class="sangue" value="69" title="41">41</option>
    <option class="sangue" value="70" title="44">44</option>
    <option class="sangue" value="71" title="43">43</option>
    <option class="sangue" value="73" title="36">36</option>
    <option class="sangue" value="74" title="37">37</option>
    <option class="sangue" value="75" title="38">38</option>
    <option class="sangue" value="76" title="39">39</option>
    <option class="sangue" value="77" title="40">40</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use "on" instead:

```
$('.form-control-select').on("change", function() {
    $('.product_middle_column').css('opacity','.4');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! it works only and exclusively at the first choice, if I change again choice, the opacity to the column is not applied

Comment: @andrea, based on what value it should change the opacity? You want to make the opacity from 1 to 0.4 and keep toggling each time you change the choice?

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay. Exactly. whenever I change my choice, the opacity should be .4 until the function is loaded (prestashop on) and I return 1 once the function is terminated. So it should be for every selection

Comment: solved by substituting 
$('.form-control-select').on("change", function() { 
to 
$(document).on('change','select', function(){  

thank you all